# Programs run fine in Eclipse, but Java can't find the source file after exporting

Tags: java, eclipse, export

Eclipse on my desktop (Windows 10), seems to be unable to export runnable jars correctly. When I export a file and attempt to run using

```
java -jar test.jar
```

cmd flashes for a second before disappearing.
When testing it using

```
java -Xdiag test.jar
pause
```

I get the error shown in the picture:

[Translation: "Error: Can't find or load main class test.jar"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4U0Ip.png)

I have no issues running a program I exported on my laptop downloaded to my desktop this way, so I'm assuming it is an issue with Eclipse, as any file exported from my desktop yields the same result.

I have looked into the MANIFEST files, but I don't really have enough experience with Java to make any sense out of it, but here is the MANIFEST for a project exported on my desktop:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader
Rsrc-Class-Path: ./
Rsrc-Main-Class: main.Main
Class-Path: .
```

Here is one from a project exported on my laptop:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Main
Class-Path: .
```

I have tried replacing the one from the project exported on my desktop with

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: main.Main
Class-Path: .
```

But it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: How are you creating this thing, what does your project look like? The first snippet is something special, you're clicking on the wrong stuff, but as you haven't explained what you're doing it's not possible to answer this question in any further detail, other than 'hey, works fine for me'.

Comment: [Here is how the project I'm trying to export is structured](https://imgur.com/a/zMD5jrr)

I have also tried to export a program consisting only of a main method with a System.out.print(), which gives the same error.

Comment: `-Xdiag` still requires you use `-jar`, if I read the doc right.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Managed to solve the issue by downloading JDK 17